# Understanding proof of characterization of the geometrically connected $k$-scheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Gortz's Algebraic Geometry Proposition 5.53 and stuck at understanding some parts :

[image]

[image]

I am trying to understand the underlined statements. Why they are true?

Q.1. Why such finite subextension $k' \subseteq \Omega$ such that $f_{ij}, g_{il} \in A_i \otimes_k k'$ for all $i,j,l$ exists?

Q.2. Why such (closed) subscheme $Y'$ exists? I understood this underlined statement as follows : Let $\mathfrak{a}_i'$ be the ideal of $A_i \otimes_k k'$ generated by $f_{ij} \in A_i\otimes_k k'$. Then $V(\mathfrak{a}_i')$ is closed in $U_i \otimes k'$ and there exists closed subscheme $Y_i'$ of $X_{k'}$ such that $Y_i' \cap (U_i \otimes k') = V(\mathfrak{a}_i')$ (true?).

And my question is, how such $Y'$ exist independently of $i$'s ?

Q.3. Why $r^{-1}(Y')=Y$ and $r^{-1}(Z')=Z$ where $r: X_{\Omega} \to X_{k'}$ is the canonical morphism ?

For Q.3., I will use his book, Proposition 4.16 :

> Proposition 4.16. Let

> $$
> \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
> \newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
> %
> \begin{array}{llllllllllll}
>  X'' \ &  \ \ra {g'} \ & X' & \ra{g} \ & X   \\
>  \da{}  & & \da{}  & & \da{}  & &   \\
>  S'' & \ra{f'} & S' & \ra{f} & S &   \\
> \end{array}
> $$

> be a commutative diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ such that the right square is cartesian. Then the left square is cartesian if and only if the entire composed diaram is cartesian.

First, note that by the Proposition 4.16, we have a cartesian square (If needed, I wiil upload proof ) :

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
 X_{\Omega} \ &  \ \ra {} \ & \operatorname{Spec}\Omega    \\
 \da{r}  & & \da{}     \\
 X_{k'} & \ra{} & \operatorname{Spec}k' &    \\
\end{array}
$$

Also, we have an other cartesian square (by the definition of the inverse image of a subscheme under a morphism) :

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
r^{-1}(Y') @>{}>>X_{\Omega}\\
@VVV @VVV{r} \\
Y' @>{}>> X_{k'}
\end{CD}$$

So, again by using the Proposition 4.16, we obtain a cartesian square :

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
r^{-1}(Y') @>{}>> \operatorname{Spec}\Omega \\
@VVV @VVV \\
Y' @>{}>> \operatorname{Spec}k'
\end{CD}$$

**So, $r^{-1}(Y') \cong Y'\times_{\operatorname{Spec}k'}\operatorname{Spec}\Omega$.**
And is this object isomorphic to $Y$? Why? How can we prove ? How can we use property of the canonical morphism $r$ and $Y$, $Y'$ ?

**Furthur attempt 1.** : It seems that $\{U_i \otimes_k \Omega \}$ forms an open covering of $X_{\Omega}$ and $\{U_i \otimes_k k' \}$ forms an open covering of $X_{k'}$ (true? c.f. Gortz's book, p.101, Cor.4.19).

As in the proof, we can write $Y' \cap (U_i \otimes k') = V(\mathfrak{a}_i ') $ where $\mathfrak{a}_i '$ is the ideal generated by the $f_{ij} \in A_i \otimes k'$ (True? If our question Q.2. is true, then there is no problem, but..)

So, $Y=\cup_iV(\mathfrak{a}_i)$ and $Y'=\cup_iV(\mathfrak{a}_i')$

How can we use this fact(?) to prove our desired equality ($r^{-1}(Y')=Y$)?

( If $r(V(\mathfrak{a}_i)) \subseteq V(\mathfrak{a}_i')$ (true?) , then we can show that $Y \subseteq r^{-1}(Y')$. And how about reverse direction? )

**Rough furthur attempt 2. :** I've tried to sketch proof of $r^{-1}(Y') = Y$ as follows ( Now I don't know that each step is certainly true ) :

As I above mentioned, $r^{-1}(Y') \cong Y'\times_{\operatorname{Spec}k'}\operatorname{Spec}\Omega$. From this,

$$ Y'\times_{\operatorname{Spec}k'}\operatorname{Spec}\Omega  = (\cup_i V(\mathfrak{a}_i')) \times_{\operatorname{Spec}k'} \operatorname{Spec}\Omega 
 \overset{\mathrm{?}}{=} \cup_i ( V(\mathfrak{a}_i') \times_{\operatorname{Spec}k'} \operatorname{Spec}\Omega)$$
$$= \cup_i(\operatorname{Spec}((A_i \otimes_k k')/\mathfrak{a}_i') \times_{\operatorname{Spec}k'}\operatorname{Spec}\Omega ) = \cup_i \operatorname{Spec}((A_i \otimes_k k')/\mathfrak{a}_i')\otimes_{k'} \Omega)$$
$$\overset{\mathrm{?}}{=} \cup_i \operatorname{Spec}((A_i\otimes_k \Omega)/\mathfrak{a}_i) = \cup_iV(\mathfrak{a}_i)=Y $$

My question is, the equalities marked by question symbol are certainly true? ; i.e.,

Q.3-1. For the first question symbol, perhaps, is next conjecture true?

> Conjecture : Let $X\to \operatorname{Spec}k$ be a scheme (possibly of finite type) with field extension $k \subseteq \Omega$.
> Let $\{U_i := \operatorname{Spec}A_i \}$ be a finite open affine covering of $X$.
> For each $i$, let $V(\mathfrak{a}_i) \subseteq U_i$ be closed subscheme of $U_i$ ($\mathfrak{a}_i \subseteq A_i$ is an ideal) such that $\cup_iV(\mathfrak{a}_i)$ is a closed subscheme of $X$.
> Then
> $$ (\cup_iV(\mathfrak{a}_i)) \times_k \Omega \cong \cup_i(V(\mathfrak{a}_i) \times _k \Omega)  $$
> ? ( The equation on the right is taken in $X_{\Omega}$ )

Q.3-2. For the second question symbol, $((A_i \otimes_k k')/\mathfrak{a}_i')\otimes_{k'} \Omega \cong (A_i\otimes_k \Omega)/\mathfrak{a}_i$ ?

Can anyone help?

Comment: For Q1, the $f_{ij} \in A_i \otimes \Omega$ are (finite) linear combinations with coefficients in $\Omega$ of elements of $A_i$. Since $\Omega/k$ is algebraic separable, there is a subextension $k’ \subset \Omega$ finite over $k$ that contains all of these coefficients – thus the $f_{ij}$ are in $A_i \otimes k’$. Q2 is basically formal.

Comment: @Aphelli : Wow~, thanks for pointing out about the form of $f_{ij}$ for Q.1. For Q.2. why do you think the question is basically formal? Is my calculation for $r^{-1}(Y')$ below true?

Comment: For Q2, your calculation isn’t really how I see things (I’m not sure whether it’s correct or not). Consider a map $f: T \rightarrow S$ of schemes and $I \subset O_S$ a quasi-coherent ideal. Then $f^{-1}(V(I))=V((f^{\sharp}I)O_T)$. Why? For $x \in T$, $x \in f^{-1}(V(I))$ iff $f(x) \in V(I)$ iff for all $g \in I$, $g(f(x))=0$ iff for all $g \in I$, $(f^{\sharp}g)(x)=0$ iff $x \in V(J)$, where $J$ is the quasi-coherent ideal generated by $f^{\sharp}I$ in $O_T$.

Comment: Some confusion : What the notation $f^{\#}$ exactly means? And, what is the relationship between $f^{-1}(V(I)) = V((f^{\#}I)\mathcal{O}_T)$ and  $r^{-1}(Y')=Y$?

Comment: In your case, $S=X_{k’}$ and $T=X_{\Omega}$ and $I$ is the quasi-coherent ideal whose restriction to $(U_i)_{k’}$ is $\mathfrak{a}_i$ (and thus $V(I)=Y$). I’m calling $f^{\sharp}$ the collection of ring homomorphisms $O_S(U) \rightarrow O_T(V)$ (for all $V \subset f^{-1}(U)$) that is part of the datum of $f$. Thus, by definition, $(f^{\sharp}I)O_T$ is the ideal whose restriction to $U_i\otimes \Omega$ is generated by the $f_{i,j}$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I will try to understand it. And Can I ask after sleeping?

Comment: @Aphelli : I upload second question above : existence of such closed subscheme $Y' \subseteq X_{k'}$. I thought this existential statement was simple and skipped it, but looking closely, now it seems not to be clear. Can you see?

Comment: Please avoid editing in new questions days after the thread was posted. Anyway: your goal is to show that the sheaves on $Y_{k’}$ defined by the $f_{i,j}$ glue together. But they glue together on $\Omega$ (ie after applying the faithfully flat base change $\otimes_{k’} \Omega$), so they glue together.

Comment: O.K. I'll be careful. I understood your comment as some glueing mechanism is involved. But now for me, your argument seems a bit vague. 1) What the notation $Y_{k'}$ means?  2) What the sheaves on $Y_{k'}$ defined by the $f_{ij}$ exactly means? 3) And why the fact that such sheaves glue together leads to our goal? 4) What does the statement "They glue together on $\Omega$" exactly means? 5) Why the gluability on $\Omega$ implies the original gluability (on $k'$?)? Perhaps, Can you explain your comment as a form of more step-by-step process? I want to understand reason of the existence of $Y'$.

Comment: 1) $Y_{k’}$ is a mistake on my part, I meant $Y’$. 2) For each $i$, there’s a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals $I_i$ on $U_i \otimes k’$ generated by the $f_{i,j}$. 4) It means that all $i,i’$, the pullbacks to $(U_i \cap U_{i’} )\otimes \Omega$ of $I_i$ and $I_{i’}$ are the same. 5) I leave the details to you as an exercise, but the idea is that for every affine $V \subset U_i \cap U_{i’}$, $I_i(V) \otimes\Omega = I_{i’}(V) \otimes \Omega$, thus it follows that $I_i(V)=I_{i’}(V)$ hence $I_i$ and $I_{i’}$ are the same on $V$ – hence the glueing.

Comment: 3) the glueing means that there is a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals $I \subset O_{X \otimes k’}$ such that its restriction to each $U_i\otimes k’$ is generated by the $f_{i,j}$. Then $Y’=V(I)$ is such that $Y’ \times \Omega$ is exactly $Y$.

Comment: Can I ask further? For the comment 3),  a) can you explain the statement "the restriction of $I$ to each $U_i \otimes k'$ is generated by the $f_{ij}$ more precisely? b) What the notation $Y' \times \Omega$ means? Fiber product over $k'$? And how the statement "$Y':=V(I)$ is such that $Y' \times \Omega$ is exactly $Y$" leads to the $Y' \cap (U_i \otimes k') = V(\mathfrak{a}_i ') $ for all $i$ ? Or perhaps, you mean, $r^{-1}(Y') \cong Y'\times_{\operatorname{Spec}k'}\operatorname{Spec}\Omega =Y $ ?

Comment: a) $U_i \otimes k’$ is an affine scheme and the $f_{ij}$ are global sections, so they generate an ideal? I’m not sure what you want more. b) Yes, $Y’ \times \Omega$ denotes $Y’ \times_{\operatorname{Spec}{k’}} \operatorname{Spec}{\Omega}$. For the rest, $Y’ \times \Omega$ (which is almost by definition $r^{-1}(Y’)$) is $V(\mathfrak{a}_i)$ on each $U_i \otimes \Omega$, because it’s the definition over $k’$.

Comment: For a), my question is, what is relationship between $I|_{U_i \otimes k'}$ and $\mathfrak{a}_i'$ (ideal generated by $f_{ij} \in A_i\otimes k'$)? Perhaps, you mean $I|_{U_i \otimes k'} = \tilde{\mathfrak{a}_i'}$ (associated sheaf)? And for (b), perhaps, you mean $r^{-1}(Y') \cap (U_i \otimes \Omega) = Y \cap (U_i \otimes \Omega)  = V(\mathfrak{a}_i)$? And it is different from $Y' \cap (U_i \otimes k') = V(\mathfrak{a_i}')$. Perhpas, can we show $r^{-1}(Y') =Y$ directly without $Y' \cap (U_i \otimes k') = V(\mathfrak{a_i}')$ ?

Comment: a) yes, I think. b) $r^{-1}(Y’) \cap (U_i \otimes \Omega)=r^{-1}(Y’ \cap (U_i \otimes k’))=r^{-1}(V(\mathfrak{a}_i’))=V(\mathfrak{a}_i)=Y \cap (U_i \otimes \Omega)$. You  can’t prove directly that $r^{-1}(Y’)=Y$ because the definition of $Y’$ is local, and given by local data from $Y$.

Comment: That proof feels pointlessly convoluted, to be honest. If $X$ is quasi-compact, then for every field extension $K/k$, $O(X_K)=O(X) \otimes_k K$. In particular, $X_{\Omega}$ is disconnected iff $O(X) \otimes \Omega$ has a nontrivial idempotent iff $O(X) \otimes L$ has a nontrivial idempotent for some finite separable $L/k$, so we get the equivalence of (iii) and (iiii).

Comment: O.K. Thanks for mention other possible approach. I will try to think about it. For b), 1) why the first equality is true? 2) And, the reason of the second equality is that : $Y' \cap (U_i \otimes_k k') := V(I)  \cap (U_i \otimes_k k') = V(I|_{U_i \otimes_k k'}) = V(\tilde{a_i}') =V(a_i')$? (I can't make sure each step certainly. Each step is really true?) 3) And for the thrid equality, if $((A_i \otimes_k k')/\mathfrak{a}_i')\otimes_{k'} \Omega \cong (A_i\otimes_k \Omega)/\mathfrak{a}_i$(which I asked in the question Q.3.2 in post) is true, then I could show the third equality. Ant is it true?

Comment: For the first equality, it seems that more information about $r$ and some relationship between $U_i \otimes \Omega$ and $U_i \otimes k'$ is needed..  c.f. Perhaps, for each $i$, $r(U_i \otimes_k \Omega) \subseteq U_i\otimes_k k'$ and the restriction $r|_{U_i \otimes_k \Omega} : U_i \otimes_k \Omega \to  U_i\otimes_k k'$ is bijective? If so, then I could show the first equality. Or if not, Is there any other way to show the first equality bypassing this statement?

Comment: Have you tried asking a real teacher? This state of affairs is unsatisfactory for you (who gets, a bit at a time, explanations that are constrained in length and turn out to be insufficient) and for me (who has to come back again and again to give more detail where I lost you). Regardless: 1) because by definition of $r$, $r^{-1}(U_i \otimes k)=U_i \otimes \Omega$. 2) yes, it’s correct. 3) Yes, this statement is (obviously) true.

Comment: No, not yet :) In fact, I am self-taught in algebraic geometry, so I often get stuck with some barriers or technical issues. I also think you are right too. Anyway I somewhat understand our overall strategy! Thank you for your patience, generosity and kind explanations.  See you later next time~