# For a $k$- scheme $X$ and $k \subseteq \Omega \subseteq L$ (separably closed extension), the canonical morphism $X_L \to X_{\Omega}$ is open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of the Proposition 5.53, (iii) => (i), he argues as follows :

Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme. Assume that there exists a separably closed extension $\Omega$ of $k$ such that $X_{\Omega}$ is connected. Then we show that $X$ is geometrically connected.

To show that, let $K$ be an extension of $k$ and let $L$ be a field containing $K$ and $\Omega$. As the canonical morphism $X_L \to X_K$ is surjective, it suffices to show that $X_L$ is connected. Consider the canonical morphism $p : X_L \to X_{\Omega}$ which is open and surjective. Thus~~..

I want to know why the $p$ is an open map. Let $X= \bigcup_i(U_i):=\bigcup_i(\operatorname{Spec}A_i)$ be an affine open covering. Then note that $\{ U_i \otimes_k\Omega\}$ forms an affine open covering of $X_{\Omega}$ and $p^{-1}(U_i\otimes_k \Omega)=U_i\otimes_kL$ ( If needed, I'll upload the proof of this equality. c.f. :[Understanding proof of characterization of the geometrically connected $k$-scheme.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4601071/understanding-proof-of-characterization-of-the-geometrically-connected-k-schem))
Since the property 'open' is local on target, to show that $p$ is open, it suffices to show that the restriction map $p|_{U_i \otimes_kL} : U_i\otimes_kL \to U_i\otimes_k\Omega$ is open for each $i$.

Then my question is,

1. $p|_{U_i \otimes_kL} = (id_{A_i}\otimes \iota)^{a} : \operatorname{Spec}(A_i\otimes_k L) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A_i \otimes_k\Omega)$, where $\iota : \Omega \hookrightarrow L$ is the inclusion ?
2. If 1) is true, then $(id_{A_i}\otimes \iota)^{a}$ is an open map ? Can be checked on the basic open sets? How?
3. If 1) is not true, then is there any other method to prove the openness of $p|_{U_i \otimes_kL}$?

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the definition of “geometrically connected” for this question?

Comment: @Zhen Lin, for every field extension $K$ of $k$, the base change $X_K$ is connected.

Comment: Apparently $\operatorname{Spec} L \to \operatorname{Spec} K$ is [universally open](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0383), so in particular $X_L \to X_K$ is open.

Comment: @Zhen Lin : Wow, O.K. Thanks~!